# regular expression to extract text surrounding anchor tag from html page

Tags: java, html, regex

Is there a way to extract text surrounding anchor tags in an html page? I am working in java and my research needs me to extract data in and around tags. I have tried searching and all I've found is regular expressions to extract only the anchor text and not the words around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1065197 ...

Comment: Not again... Why not just use parser?

Comment: Use an HTML parser instead.  Also, see Luiggi's link.

Comment: Parsing html with regex is not something I would take on unless it was a small amount and pretty well known. I recommend something like jsoup http://jsoup.org/download which is a library specifically for web-parsing. What exactly do you mean by around tags? Does that mean you want to know what tags are next to the nested tag?

Comment: You might also consider using the http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html parser to render HTML as plain text.

Comment: @StreamingBits by around tags i mean <p> hello <a>abcd</a> how are you </p>  i need to extract the text outside the anchor thats "hello" and "how are you"

Comment: [Kinda tricky](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the way to go to parse html, but ..
Quick and dirty, if you have to have a regex

`"([^<>]*)<a>([^<>]*)</a>([^<>]*)"`

```
 ( [^<>]* )         # (1)
 <a>
 ( [^<>]* )         # (2)
 </a>
 ( [^<>]* )         # (3)
```

"is there `a way to provide the number of characters before and after the anchor text`"?

Sure. You can supply either min/max `{m,n}` or exact `{exact}` or a mixture.
Example:

---

Before = 5, after = 5 to 10
`"([^<>]{5})<a>([^<>]*)</a>([^<>]{5,10})"`

Before = 1 to no-limit, after = 0 to 10
`"([^<>]{1,})<a>([^<>]*)</a>([^<>]{0,10})"`

---

And there are many other possible variations, including mixing literals in as well.

Comment: thanks.. this makes more sense :) is there also a way to provide the number of characters before and after the anchor text??